# Need help in constructing a JSON payload in DW 2.0

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft, mule4

I have the below keys/values stored in Object Store. For example 'Employee_Number' is the key and below is the value/object associated for this key.

```
{
        employeeMetaColumn = Employee_Number,
        employeeMetaText = Employee Number,
        employeeMetaType = SECT,
        employeeMetaId = 18
}
```

Likewise I have many such key and value pairs as shown in the payload below (when I do Retrieve All object Store operation I get the below payload # 1). As we can see its not JSON.

**

> Payload # 1 from Object Store.

**

```
{
    Employee_Number = {
        employeeMetaColumn = Employee_Number,
        employeeMetaText = Employee Number,
        employeeMetaType = SECT,
        employeeMetaId = 18
    }, Country_of_Birth = {
        employeeMetaColumn = Country_of_Birth,
        employeeMetaText = Country of Birth,
        employeeMetaType = SLD,
        employeeMetaId = 19
    }
}
```

I have below payload # 2 which I need to use for constructing the final payload # 3. Here Employee_Number maps to the key in the object Store ( for example 'Employee_Number' as shown in  the above payload). So I want to use this key to fetch the value from object Store.

**

> Payload # 2

**

```
{
  "employee": [
    {
      "Employee_Number": "123456",
      "Country_of_Birth": "USA",
    }
  ]
}
```

Now I need to construct the below Payload # 3

**

> Payload # 3

**

```
{
"parameters": [{
        "employeeParamValue": [
            "123456"
        ],
        "employeeMetaColumn": "Employee_Number",
        "employeeMetaText": "Employee Number",
        "employeeMetaType": "SECT",
        "employeeMetaId": 18,
        
    },
    {
        "employeeParamValue": [
            "USA"
        ],
        "employeeMetaColumn": "Country_of_Birth",
        "employeeMetaText": "Country of Birth",
        "employeeMetaType": "SLD"
        "employeeMetaId": 19,
    }
]
}
```

note: employeeParamValue is an array eventhough it just has one value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
%dw 2.0
var lookup = {
    "Employee_Number": {
        "employeeMetaColumn": "Employee_Number",
        "employeeMetaText": "Employee Number",
        "employeeMetaType": "SECT",
        "employeeMetaId": 18
    }, 
    "Country_of_Birth": {
        "employeeMetaColumn": "Country_of_Birth",
        "employeeMetaText": "Country of Birth",
        "employeeMetaType": "SLD",
        "employeeMetaId": 19
    }
}
var in = {
  "employee": [
    {
      "Employee_Number": "123456",
      "Country_of_Birth": "USA",
    }
  ]
}
output application/json
---
parameters: in.employee[0]
    pluck ((value, key, index) -> 
        {
            "employeeParamValue":[value], (lookup[key])
        }
    )
```

Output

```
{
  "parameters": [
    {
      "employeeParamValue": [
        "123456"
      ],
      "employeeMetaColumn": "Employee_Number",
      "employeeMetaText": "Employee Number",
      "employeeMetaType": "SECT",
      "employeeMetaId": 18
    },
    {
      "employeeParamValue": [
        "USA"
      ],
      "employeeMetaColumn": "Country_of_Birth",
      "employeeMetaText": "Country of Birth",
      "employeeMetaType": "SLD",
      "employeeMetaId": 19
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jarus for your answer, it works when I read the entire payload from Object Store but my requirement is not to read the entire payload from Object Store instead fetch only values associated for the employee key attributes ( var 'in' created above)

var lookup which is referred above is stored in Object Store for instance, the key Employee_Number needs to be passed to object Store to get the value and then use it for final payload construction, like wise this will need to be repeated for all the attributes present in the employee payload ( var 'in' created in the answer above).

Comment: @Sunny85 That's not what the question is asking for. Also the solution's  output matches the example output in the question. You should clarify better the question, though I would recommend that you try adapting the method in the solution to your needs first.

Comment: @Sunny85 As Aled rightly mentioned, your question doesn't mention anything about retrieving the object that you have asked in the comment. However, it is relatively simple.

Comment: You can have the logic for retrieving the key-value from the object store in a private flow (not a subflow). In the dataweave script, you can use the lookup() function and pass the flow name and the employee key attribute as arguments. You can read more about lookup() in docs. Essentially, you need to replace (lookup[key]) in the solution with the lookup() function. The output of the lookup() function will be the resulting payload of the object store flow, which in this case will be the matching key and its value retrieved from the object store. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks heaps @jarus. the steps mentioned by you worked and was able to use lookup() to get the values for the key.